# with open() throwing errors on a json file

Tags: python, json

So I'm super new to coding and I wanted to design a text based RPG as sort of a fun way to learn some stuff and I picked out the language Python because it was named after Monty Python. How perfect right? Well, that is what I thought until trying to get rooms to load.

I am using json files to store my room names, descriptions, and exits then trying to call them in python via a method I saw on YouTube, here is the code:

```
def getRoom(id):
    ret = None
    with open(str(id)+".json", "r") as f:
        jsontext = f.read()
        d = json.loads(jsontext)
        d['id'] = id
        ret = Room(**d)
```

This threw an IOError directory or file not found, so I added a try statement like so:

```
def getRoom(id):
    ret = None
try:
    with open(str(id)+".json", "r") as f:
        jsontext = f.read()
        d = json.loads(jsontext)
        d['id'] = id
        ret = Room(**d)
except IOError:
    print("An error occured")
```

However now I am getting an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'" off my look command which I have coded like so:

```
def look(player, args):
    print(player.loc.name)
    print("")
    print (player.loc.description)
```

In case this matters here is my json file that I have named 1.json:

```
{
    "name": "A Small Bedroom",
    "description": "The old bed room has probably seen many people over the years as the inn sits along a major trade route. The floor boards show wear and creak as you walk over them.",
    "neighbors": {"w":2}
}
```

EDIT:

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "game.py", line 79, in <module> 
       main(player) File "game.py", line 68, in main
           player.loc = getRoom(1)
   File "/home/illyduss/Urth/Locations/room.py", line 6, in getRoom 
       with open(str(id)+".json", "r") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.json'
```

Comment: Please add the *full traceback* you receive. Remove your `try/except` clause and show us the error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 79, in <module>
    main(player)
  File "game.py", line 68, in main
    player.loc = getRoom(1)
  File "/home/illyduss/Urth/Locations/room.py", line 6, in getRoom
    with open(str(id)+".json", "r") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.json'

Comment: Remove your try catch, it doesn't help and only hides the problem to you. Your file does not exist...

Comment: Where do you put your `1.json`? Together with `game.py`?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code example. The `try/except`-block is probably wrong the way you put it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error clearly says that the file is not to be found. Try the following.
1. make sure that the filename `1.json` is available from where you are calling the python interpretor.

for example: if you are calling `$ python game/game.py`, then the file should be in the present working directory, not in `game` dir

Try using absolute paths if you can

```
import os
base_dir = /path/to/json/dir
filename = str(id)+".json"
abs_file = os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
with open(abs_file, "r"):
    #do stuff
```

If you need the json files to be relative to the game.py file and still need the game file to be called from elsewhere, a good practice would be to define base_dir using `__file__` attribute of the python file

`base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)`

The reason you're geting `NoneType` error is that somehow the loc variable is being set to None. which means that you are passing None to the Player's constructor. Since you haven't provided the code where you initialize player, I am assuming that you're passing the result of getRoom() as loc to the constructor. If that is the case, make sure that the value returned by getRoom is not None. you need an explicit return statement at the end of the function. return ret . by default any function without a return statement returns None. That could be your issue

Comment: I'm still getting the Nonetype error from name in the look command. Here is a traceback on that.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "game.py", line 79, in <module>
        main(player)
      File "game.py", line 76, in main
        runCMD(input[0], input[1], player)
      File "game.py", line 63, in runCMD
        commands[cmd](player, args)
      File "/home/illyduss/Urth/Commands/commands.py", line 20, in look
        print(player.loc.name)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: how are you populating the `loc` attribute of player ?

Comment: In the __init__ of my player class I call it. Here is the code to that. Then in my game file I set player.loc = getRoom(1)      `class Player(Character):
 def __init__(self, name, hp, str, int, loc):
  Character.__init__(self, name, hp, str)
  self.str = str
  self.int = int
  self.loc = loc
  self.name = name

  self.inventory = set()`

Comment: somehow the `loc` variable is being set to `None`. which means that you are passing `None` to the Player's constructor. Since you haven't provided the code where you initialize player, I am assuming that you're passing the result of `getRoom()` as `loc` to the constructor. If that is the case, make sure that the value returned by `getRoom` is not `None`. you need an explicit `return` statement at the end of the function. `return ret` . by default any function without a `return` statement returns `None`. That could be your issue.

Comment: Totally worked. I originally had Return ret in the code to and have no clue why I later removed it, but it is working! Thanks for helping me solve the issue and I know I learned a little during all of this.

Comment: glad to help.
I'll edit the answer to accommodate the changes.